# How to export to Excel in number format from SQL Server selected statement query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, export

I tried following things,

1. I converted select statement column field as float/money,
2. I made empty excel sheet with only header and I formatted respective columns to number before import

I am exporting more than 600,000 records.

I cannot convert to number after I export, because it's taking lot of time for each column with huge records, sometimes it will get hang or the application will crash and close

```
CREATE Table #Records
(
    Quantity float,
    Amount money,
    TotalAmt money
)

INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
                       'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\Export\1.xlsx;', 
                       'SELECT Quantity,Amount,TotalAmt FROM [Sheet1$]') 
    SELECT Quantity, Amount, TotalAmt
    FROM #Records rec
    ORDER BY Date ASC
```

Actually after I exported to Excel, the column shows as Text formatted column,

I need to export as number format, so that, the user will do further calculations based on values of number format columns.

Comment: "I'm putting more than half a million rows into an excel sheet" - should be nice and usable! So what type is the exported column? Show a screenshot of what you get vs what you want

Comment: @CaiusJard I ask the same question that you ask, that what you are going to do with half million records?, actually it's not half million. it's more than that you cannot imagine. we split the excel sheet.

Comment: Try using DOUBLE data type for all 3 columns in the table. Format all columns to NUMBER format in excel. Also, make sure there are no NULL values in the output. Let me know if it works.